# How can I fix the Batsuit?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

As I played through the campaign, Batman started looking a bit *rough* around the edges.  His cape is torn, and he's got tons of damage to his Batsuit.  I realize this is all cosmetic, but now that I've finished the campaign I'd kind of like to get him back to "mint condition [NRFB](http://reviews.ebay.com/What-does-MIB-NIB-NRFB-NOS-mean_W0QQugidZ10000000003599297) Batman A++++" condition.

I know there are some "alternate Bataman" skins floating around as well (mostly through pre-order and DLC bonuses, I assume) that I could switch to, so I assume there's got to be some sort of "skin menu" I'm missing here.

Besides calling Alfred and asking for the world's toughest sewing kit, how do I "fix" Batman's outfit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short of switching into another suit (gotten through a preorder bonus, or through DLC), there is no way to repair the suit.

Beating the game unlocks the option to change into other suits, however, you can only change costumes before you start playing.  When you choose either "Continue Story" or "Continue New Game +" you get the option to change your suit. You will also get the option to change suits in the challenge modes.

Comment: If I had access to another suit, how would I know?  Is there a menu somewhere or something?

Comment: @agent86 Edited to add that information. :)

Comment: @AshleyNunn Can you actually switch back to an undamaged Batsuit in the suit select, or are you stuck with the damaged one?

Comment: @Alex you are stuck with the damaged one, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

The costume menu is in the main menu (Catwoman campaign, Riddler challenges etc.). On Console (Xbox, PS3) and PC, you can press these buttons on the main menu screen to access it for the campaign

> left left down down left left right up up down

and then you can continue the campaign in a new suit!

Answer (score -2):

On the Xbox or PS3 there isn't a way to fix the default Batsuit, unless you can find a way to covertly mod your Xbox (but that is REALLY hard).

As for the computer version you have two methods:

1. You can get into the game info and tweak it so that your suit won't take any damage.
2. You can use the mod where you can create you own custom Batsuit, and then once you finish the game you can choose the costume you created at the costume selection.

Comment: And how would we do that?

Answer (score -3):

Cheats and a new game for the new batsuit.But if you like the old and the busted don't use cheats and just play the game.